# Is there any way to hash a password with bcrypt before sending it with POST method?

Tags: javascript, security, passwords, http-post, bcrypt

I want to know if there is way to hash a password with bcrypt, before i send it through the POST method from the login to the processing page, to improve the security of login script. I can not use SSL protection to do so.

Comment: This won't improve your security, someone could still sniff your traffic and get the hashed password, then use that to authenticate.

Comment: So is there any way to improve security without SSL.

Comment: Hate to tell you this, but this is what https/ssl is for. That is why it was made. Whatever/whoever is preventing you from using SSL is preventing you from having a secure application.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. I will try to make use of SSL then i can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, even if you did what you propose, it would still not result in a secure connection, thus rendering it vulnerable to a [Man in the Middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack. As discussed in the below comments, any hashing you do client-side renders the password pointless as it will require you to send the hash over the wire, to compare to another hash server-side. The attacker (MitM) could just use the hash to authenticate in this case.

If you want secure communication, you must (at least) implement TLS/SSL.

Comment: But still is there any way to hash the password using bcrypt. I found out that there is an implementation of bcrypt in ruby. Can i possibly do it with ruby?

Comment: (I'm not a Ruby programmer but...)Ruby is still a server-side language, so you would still be sending the password in plaintext at first. If you were to hash it on the client, then verify that hash at the server, your hash essentially becomes the new password, which you are still sending in plaintext.

Comment: I am unable to understand that if information can be stolen using man in the middle attack, then why hashing the password from the client side will not improve security

Comment: @MarcusAdams and Sid, He wouldn't need to reverse a bcrypt hash, I meant for the encryption option, not the hashing. Regardless, it does not matter: Hashing is for improving security when the attacker has access to the passwords in the database. To protect against man-in-the-middle, you need a secure connection. Hashing the password client side would keep the attacker from knowing the password. It will also keep you from knowing the password. If you want to authenticate them, you'll have to compare the hashes. That means that the attacker can authenticate with the accessible hashes.

Comment: @Sid , MarcusAdams. This is getting off-topic for SO. If you want to know more, you could make a post at Security.stackexchange, where people far more knowledgeable and specialized can help explain why client-side hashing won't improve security.

Comment: @Sid I will admit my wording is ambiguous, and will try to edit it. What I was trying to say: some form of client-side encryption: can be reverse engineered; hashing: can't be reverse-engineered, but also means you don't know the password. Your answer says essentially what I am saying, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

If you hashed a password with bcrypt, given a sufficiently strong password, and a salt, the password would be safe.

If the hash that was passed in didn't match the hash on the server, you could refuse access.

However, the main problem with your design is that now the password is no longer required to gain access to the system. The hash now becomes all that's needed to authenticate. The hash has thus become a suitable replacement for the password. Well, you've just passed that pseudo-password in the open, unencrypted, to an unverified server.

Passwords should be hashed before they are stored on the server using bcrypt or something similar. However, passwords should generally be passed in to the server (in clear text over an encrypted connection) and hashed there so that you can ensure that the client actually knows the password.

One alternative to that method, and instead of SSL, that you might consider is Digest authentication, but this only works because every call to the server is re-authenticated. If you use any kind of token based session, it could be available to replay and MitM attacks, so it must be encrypted. Also, Digest authentication is kind of old, and not as cryptographically secure as TLS, and there's no server identity verification, so we still end up back at HTTPS (SSL/TLS).

HTTPS (SSL/TLS) provides server identify verification and provides full end to end encryption, which is what you should use. You could mimic all the protections that SSL provides, but it seems like a lot of work trying to do something that's already there and implemented so easily.

Comment: +1 for a clear explanation; could you check my edit and see if it is now more accurate/clear. I don't feel like you said anything that was counter to what I was saying, just that my wording was ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you everybody. I will use SSL protection for my login script